# cant get code to insert to table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble trying to get some values to insert into one of my tables.
It used to work fine but have recently changed my database and now does not insert.
I have stared at it for so long now i cannot see what is wrong, hopefully some one can see what is bound to be an obvious mistake.

The code is:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
$plan = preg_replace('#[^A-za-z0-9 ?!.,]#i', '', $_POST['plan']);
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM maingroup WHERE groupName ='$g'";
$for_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($for_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$user = $row["owner"];

    $sessAdd = "INSERT INTO training (user, groupName, date, sessDate, plan)       
          VALUES('$user','$g',now(),'$date','$plan')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sessAdd);
    $gid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);

}  
header("location: groupPage.php?g=$g");
}
?>


<form name="addSess" id="addSess" method="post">
Date of Training: <input type="text" size="12" id="date" /></br></br>
               Training:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<textarea name="plan" id="plan" rows="10" cols="80">

</textarea>
<script>  
CKEDITOR.replace( 'plan' );
</script>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Training" onclick="javascript:return   validateMyForm();">
</form>
```

I have other pages that insert fine using more or less the same code just changing the table names and columns etc. The '$g' is established at the top of the page and gets the group info. 
They all include a php script that connects to the database that works fine on the other pages also and elsewhere on the same page it calls data from another table so don't think its a connection problem. I have obviously gone blind to my error so am really hoping someone can see it.
Thank you to anyone that tries.

Comment: `name attribute` missing at date input text box

Comment: Plus `$g` is undefined in your code!!

Comment: Replace this VALUES('$user','$g',now(),'$date','$plan')";  with VALUES("'.$user.'","'.$g.'",now(),"'.$date'","'.$plan.'")";

Comment: Thank you @Saty the name attribute seems to have done the trick!.

Comment: Can I post a answer??@dyer926

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to insert

```
$sessAdd = "INSERT INTO training (user, groupName, date, sessDate, plan) VALUES('$user','$g',".now().",'$date','$plan')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$sessAdd = "INSERT INTO training (user, groupName, date, sessDate, plan)       
          VALUES('$user','$g',now(),'$date','$plan')";
```

By

```
$sessAdd = "INSERT INTO training (user, groupName, sessDate, plan)       
          VALUES('$user','$g','$date','$plan')";
```

Check your table whtr field `date` has default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`